# i have output shows 404 error in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

i download example from site and run but it shows 404 error-
HTTP Status 404 - 
type Status report

message 
description The requested resource is not available.

---

http://tutorialspointexamples.com/spring-mvc-multiple-controller-program-code-eclipse-download-pdf/

Comment: which url you are callilng ?

Answer (score 0):

404 Not Found means that the requested ressource can not be found by the server.
Maybe you have a typo in your document's name or in the url you enter in the browser.

Comment: If you want to learn about java and spring take a look at the spring guides. You create them line by line and you get the complete source code as well.
https://spring.io/guides

Comment: what is the result when you hit : http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/sayHello

Comment: I get the same error. Localhost is always your local computer 127.0.0.1. It wont work at other people. For this case you need a webserver. Are you sure your local tomcat is running?

Comment: yes tomcat  running...wait it showing error-----' Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load .  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.